# element that appear more that once in the list in Python

Tags: python, list, element

Please help (I know that it's a silly question):

I have a list `d = [' ABA', ' AAB', ' BAA', ' BAA', ' AAB', ' ABA']`. How can I exclude elements that appear more than once?

Comment: What's the expected output? `[]` or `[' ABA', ' AAB', ' BAA']`?

Comment: Do you want us to drop values which occur more than once, or just exclude multiple occurrences of them? Do you care about preserving the original order of the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to a set then back again:

```
list(set(d))
```

If order matters, you can pass the values through a dict that remembers the original indices. This approach, while expressible as a single expression, is considerably more complicated:

```
[x for (i, x) in sorted((i, x) for (x, i) in dict((x, i) for (i, x) in reversed(list(enumerate(d)))).iteritems())]
```

Of course, you don't have to use comprehensions. For this problem, a fairly simple solution is available:

```
a = []
for x in d:
    if x not in a:
        a.append(x)
```

Note that both the order-preserving solutions assume that you want to keep the first occurrence of each duplicated element.

Comment: Unfortunately your for-loop solution is O(N**2)

Comment: @John: Yes, the for-loop is O(N**2). Whether that's unfortunate or not depends on a few factors, including the size of the input array and how much duplication there is.

Comment: What does list(set(d)) 'list' means here?

Comment: It's the type of Python lists; i.e., `[1, 2, 3].__class__ == list`. Its constructor accepts any sequence, including `set`.

Answer (score 15):

To **exclude** items from the list that appear more than once:

```
d = [x for x in d if d.count(x) == 1]
```

For the example provided above, d will bind to an empty list.

Others have posted good solutions to **remove duplicates**.

Comment: Note that looping over `d` and finding the count of each element is always O(n^2). Use `...for x in set(d)...` instead for lists with many duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you got a list named `Words` and a list `UniqueWords`, start a loop on `Words`, on each iteration you check if the list `UniqueWords` contains the iterated element, if so then `continue`, if not then add it to the UniqueWords. In the end you will have a list without duplicates.  Another way you could do is a loop in a loop and instead of adding you'd remove it if it was found more than once :)

I bet there are far more efficient ways though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about the order, `d = list(set(d)))`.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters check out the `unique_everseen` function in the [itertools recpies](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) documentation. It give a relatively clean iterator-based solution.

If order doesn't matter, convert to a set.

Answer (score -1):

If you shouldn't have done that already, make sure to read [the python docs on itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), especially product(), permutations() and combinations().